# Applying SKShader to multiple layers

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, shader

In a game I am working on, I use multiple layers to manage the background scenery like so:

1. Background
2. Background Obstacles
3. Foreground Obstacles

I am using a displacement shader to create a ripple effect, but I'm not sure how to apply it to the entire background section. Each layer is an individual SKNode where I add different SKSprites.

I want the ripple effect to affect all layers, but I can't apply a shader to a SKNode.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot apply one shader effect to multiple layers, so what you would likely need to do is capture the state of the other layers by making then siblings in a parent node and capturing the output of the node, like this:

```
SKTexture *captureTexture = [skView textureFromNode:node];
```

Then assign this texture to one node and attach the shader to that Node. You may not be able to get full FPS updates with this capture approach, but I this may be the only way to get it working.

Comment: there are other ways to get a texture from a node, you can play around with core graphics to get faster results if needed

Comment: Knight, what are you talking about? The textureFromNode API directly captures at the graphic layer at the level of OpenGL or Metal APIs. CoreGraphics is a user level API dealing directly with memory buffers. The only other way might be to use SKEffectNode to implement this effect, but there is nothing "faster" about CoreGraphics.

Comment: could you point to some kind of documentation that this is what `textureFromNode` is using. `textureFromNode` in itself has some overhead to it, and must be performed on the main thread.  If merging some textures together is all that is needed, then taking texture data and placing them into memory buffers is exactly what you want to be doing and I have found it faster to work in CG to achieve this than to be using textureFromNode.

Comment: Apple provides no documentation on how things are actually implemented. But, the way it works depends on the implementation. For example, SpriteKit is implemented on top of either OpenGL or Metal APIs. The SKEffectNode is another possible implementation in that a shader could be attached so as to read from the captured buffer directly. The point of this direct logic is to avoid using the CPU to do processing since the GPU is what would be used to process the images.

Comment: I agree, and I do understand how Sprite Kit works,  but we do not know if that particular method is utilizing the opengl/metal api, and with how slow that method is, it is possible that it is not using it, since I have found that using Core Graphics actually worked faster when dealing with simple texture merges. Documentation would have helped if you knew of any that existed.